# Cannot resolve symbol 'Builder'

Tags: java, android, builder, floating-action-button

I'm trying to use FloatingActionButton in my app but it fails. I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Builder' after adding the piece of code below the onCreate();..

```
ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);

    FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(icon)
            .build();
```

here is my dependencies

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. i have replaced screenshot by code.

Comment: please help me how can i fix this problem.

Comment: thanks for everyone. finally i have solved that problem. i should import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton; instated of android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

Comment: Keep in mind you are now using an MIT-licensed third-party library, which means you have to comply with an attribution requirement. You have to include the [CircularFloatingActionMenu license notice](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu/blob/master/LICENCE) in your APK file.